# Is the set $A=\left\{x\in\mathbb{N}:x\notin A\right\}$ legitimate?

Tags: set-theory

I believe it's illegitimate otherwise there will be a contradiction (an object is neither inside nor outside $A$). But I don't know which principle prohibits this(sorry about being ignorant in math), maybe because we can't self-reffering when defining a set.

Can anyone helps? Thanks.

Comment: The formula $x\notin A$ has two free variables (since $A$ is not a pre-existing formula/abbreviation/designation). For Separation, you need formulas with a single free variable. That is, this doesn't even parse: it is not a well formed formula.

Comment: Get it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's to stop dong stuff like this that we got rid of Naive set theory.  Most mathematicians these days work inside $ZFC$,  look up $ZFC set theory$ or $ZF$ set theory if you want to learn more.  @ArturoMagidin , should probably convert that to an answer so it can be accepted?

Comment: There is nothing sorry to being ignorant at maths. Not knowing what principles is not the fixed mark of checking math skills.

Comment: This is not a well formed formula that explicitly defines a set, but it is a well formed predicate that one can apply to sets. It would be true on subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ that coincide with their complements. But because there are no such subsets the predicate is identically false. You *can* use such "self-referring" predicates to define objects implicitly, but *only if* you can prove that they exist and are unique.

Comment: @Conifold "You can use such "self-referring" predicates to define objects implicitly, but only if you can prove that they exist and are unique." I don't quite understand this. Would you mind an example?

Comment: $A=\left\{x\in\mathbb{Z}: x+1\in A\right\}$ imposes a condition on $A\subset\mathbb{Z}$, which is that $x$ is in $A$ if and only if $x+1$ is in $A$. If we add that $A$ is non-empty this uniquely defines $\mathbb{Z}$ itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The axiom schema of separation states that for all formula $\psi$ such that $y$ does not appear free in $\psi$, the universal closure of
$$\exists y \forall x (x\in y \leftrightarrow (x\in z \land \psi))$$
holds in every model.

You're trying to form
$$\exists A \forall x (x\in A\leftrightarrow (x\in\mathbb{N}\land x\not\in A))$$
this violates the restriction that $A$ may not appear free in $x\not\in A$.

There's a similar restriction with the axiom schema of replacement so it can't be done via that route either.

Answer (score 0):

A subset of a set $A$ is defined as $S = \{x\mid x\in A\wedge P(x)\}$ where $P(x)$ is a predicate in the free variable $x$. Since ''$x\not\in A$'' is such a predicate, the set described above is legitimate.

Comment: $A$ is the empty set,  as $\forall x\, (x\in A\implies (x\in \Bbb N\land x\not\in A)\implies x\not\in A).$

Comment: If you are right, then there is a contradiction. You may recheck my post, hh.

Comment: No, $P$ must be a predicate where $A$ does not appear free, so "$x\notin A$" is not such a $P$.